# Apache superset mark chart regions

Tags: apache-superset

Is it possible to mark/highlight regions in a superset line chart or would I need to create a custom chart?

I have a chart showing device voltage and I want to highlight where the low/critical/normal voltage range is.

I can sort of hack it by adding annotation lines and increasing the thickness of the lines to 150. This sort of works but falls apart when the y axis range changes.

Any better ideas?

[image]